# I'm getting a match on each join and only want to return one value

Tags: sql, join

I'm doing a join on two tables.  The first table has transactions and the second table has budgets.

I would only like to return the budget once but as there are multiple transactions in the first table it is returning the budget on each matched row.

I'm new to SQL and would like some advise on how to do this?  Is there a simple code or will I need to count the number of times it returns the value and then average it?

The Transaction Data will look something like this

```
TransDate |  AccountDesc   |    Total    
1 July    |  Marketing     |    $50,000  
14 July   |  Marketing     |    $10,000
3 August  |  Marketing     |    $12,500
```

The budget for marketing in July is $30,000 and the budget in August is $80,000

When I do a join it returns the following results

```
TransDate |  AccountDesc   |    Total     |  Budget 
1 July    |  Marketing     |    $50,000   |  $30,000
14 July   |  Marketing     |    $10,000   |  $30,000
3 August  |  Marketing     |    $12,500   |  $80,000
```

When i put this into Excel and do a sum it shows July as having a budget of $60,000 when it should only be $30,000.

I would like to see the following:

```
TransDate |  AccountDesc   |    Total     |  Budget 
1 July    |  Marketing     |    $50,000   |  $30,000
14 July   |  Marketing     |    $10,000   |  
3 August  |  Marketing     |    $12,500   |  $80,000
```

The query looks as follows:

```
SELECT GLTrans.OPENYEAR as FinYear
, RTRIM(GLTrans.REFRENCE) AS Reference
, RTRIM(GLTrans.DSCRIPTN) AS Description
, GLTrans.TRXDATE
,
CASE
    WHEN MONTH(GLTrans.TRXDATE) = 1 THEN '07 January'
    WHEN MONTH(GLTrans.TRXDATE) = 2 THEN '08 February'
    WHEN MONTH(GLTrans.TRXDATE) = 3 THEN '09 March'
    WHEN MONTH(GLTrans.TRXDATE) = 4 THEN '10 April'
    WHEN MONTH(GLTrans.TRXDATE) = 5 THEN '11 May'
    WHEN MONTH(GLTrans.TRXDATE) = 6 THEN '12 June'
    WHEN MONTH(GLTrans.TRXDATE) = 7 THEN '01 July'
    WHEN MONTH(GLTrans.TRXDATE) = 8 THEN '02 August'
    WHEN MONTH(GLTrans.TRXDATE) = 9 THEN '03 September'
    WHEN MONTH(GLTrans.TRXDATE) = 10 THEN '04 October'
    WHEN MONTH(GLTrans.TRXDATE) = 11 THEN '05 November'
    ELSE '06 December'
END AS TransDate
, SUM(GLTrans.CRDTAMNT) * -1 AS Credit
, GLTrans.DEBITAMT AS Debit
, GLTrans.DEBITAMT - GLTrans.CRDTAMNT AS Total
,
CASE
    WHEN GLCode.ACTNUMBR_1 = 6238 THEN 'Subscriptions'
    WHEN GLCode.ACTNUMBR_1 = 6212 THEN 'Conference Expenses'
    WHEN GLCode.ACTNUMBR_1 = 6216 THEN 'Entertainment - Business Development'
    WHEN GLCode.ACTNUMBR_1 = 6217 THEN 'Entertainment -Staff Engagement'
    WHEN GLCode.ACTNUMBR_1 = 6250 THEN 'Marketing & Promotion'
    WHEN GLCode.ACTNUMBR_1 = 6265 THEN 'Staff Awards'
    WHEN GLCode.ACTNUMBR_1 = 6270 THEN 'Staff Training'
    WHEN GLCode.ACTNUMBR_1 = 6272 THEN 'Travelling'
    WHEN GLCode.ACTNUMBR_1 = 6268 THEN 'Technical Publications'
    WHEN GLCode.ACTNUMBR_1 = 6237 THEN 'Legels Fees'
    WHEN GLCode.ACTNUMBR_1 = 6262 THEN 'Staff Hiring Costs'
    ELSE 'General Expenses'
END AS AccountDesc
, RTRIM(GLCode.ACTNUMST) AS AccountNum
, GLCode.ACTNUMBR_2 AS ServiceLine
, GLCode.ACTNUMBR_4 AS Partner
, GLTrans.DEX_ROW_ID
FROM GL20000 As GLTrans
LEFT JOIN GL00105 AS GLCode ON GLCode.ACTINDX = GLTrans.ACTINDX
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT [BUDGETID]
      ,RTRIM([ACTNUMBR_1]) + '-' + RTRIM([ACTNUMBR_2]) + '-' + RTRIM([ACTNUMBR_3]) + '-' + RTRIM([ACTNUMBR_4]) AS Account
      ,[PERIODDT]
      ,[PERIODID]
      ,[BUDGETAMT]
      ,[ACCATNUM]
      ,[ACTINDX]
      ,[YEAR1]
  FROM [GPSRV].[dbo].[GL00201]
  WHERE BUDGETID = '2016 BUDGET'
  AND [ACTNUMBR_1] IN ('6238', '6212', '6216', '6217', '6250', '6265', '6270', '6272', '6268', '6237', '6262', '6213', '6214', '6215')
  AND ACTNUMBR_2  IN ('RAS', 'BRI', 'COR')
  ) AS Budget on Budget.Account = GLCode.ACTNUMST
WHERE GLCode.ACTNUMBR_1 IN ('6238', '6212', '6216', '6217', '6250', '6265', '6270', '6272', '6268', '6237', '6262', '6213', '6214', '6215')
AND GLCode.ACTNUMBR_2  IN ('RAS', 'BRI', 'COR')
and GLTrans.TRXDATE >= '2015-07-01 00:00:00.000'
AND GLTrans.TRXDATE <= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
GROUP BY
      GLTrans.OPENYEAR
    , GLTrans.REFRENCE
    , GLTrans.DSCRIPTN
    , GLTrans.TRXDATE
    , GLTrans.DEBITAMT
    , GLCode.ACTNUMST
    , GLCode.ACTNUMBR_1
    , GLCode.ACTNUMBR_2
    , GLCode.ACTNUMBR_4
    , GLTrans.TRXDATE
    , GLTrans.DEBITAMT
    , GLTrans.CRDTAMNT
    , GLTrans.DEX_ROW_ID
```

The relationship between the two tables is pretty limited.  First of all I am working with Microsoft GP if this provides any additional assistance.

The transaction table has 
The financial year.
A transaction date.
The General Ledger code (Code, Location, Department, partner)

The budget table has
The Budget ID
The General Ledger code in it's segments (Code, Location, Department, partner)
The Period ID (Financial Month)
The Budget Amount

Otherwise there is nothing to join them.

Once again thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and provide:  (1) sample data; (2) desired results; (3) the query you are currently using; (4) the database you are currently using (as a tag on the question).

Comment: It sounds like you need something like `select sum(transaction_amounts), budget_amount from mytable group by budget`

Comment: I need to return each value though from the transactions table as the business wants to be able to drill into each line.  The end goal is to add this query into Excel and place the returned value into a pivot table.

Comment: Gordon Linoff my query at present looks like this...

Comment: @DebbsR your sample code probably won't fit in a comment, and even if it does it will render terribly. Instead, click on the "edit" text underneath your question to add your sample code to the original question. you can also highlight it and click on the `{ }` button to have SO render it nicely for you.

Comment: Thanks Joe.  I'm a bit of a Rookie!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing quite a bit here, the code sample provided doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me in the context of the question asked. But hopefully this will be a starting point. I'll be happy to add to / modify this if you can provide some clarification about how you want the joins to work.

```
SELECT
 GLTrans.OPENYEAR as [FinYear],
 rtrim(GLTrans.REFRENCE) as [Reference],
 rtrim(GLTrans.DSCRIPTN) as [Description],
 GLTrans.TRXDATE,
 right('0' + cast(month(dateadd(m, 6, GLTrans.TRXDATE)) as char(2)),2) + ' ' + datename(m, GLTrans.TRXDATE) as [TransDate],
 sum(GLTrans.CRDTAMNT) * -1 as [Credit],
 GLTrans.DEBITAMT as [Debit],
 GLTrans.DEBITAMT - GLTrans.CRDTAMNT as [Total],
 CASE GLCode.ACTNUMBR_1
    WHEN 6238 THEN 'Subscriptions'
    WHEN 6212 THEN 'Conference Expenses'
    WHEN 6216 THEN 'Entertainment - Business Development'
    WHEN 6217 THEN 'Entertainment -Staff Engagement'
    WHEN 6250 THEN 'Marketing & Promotion'
    WHEN 6265 THEN 'Staff Awards'
    WHEN 6270 THEN 'Staff Training'
    WHEN 6272 THEN 'Travelling'
    WHEN 6268 THEN 'Technical Publications'
    WHEN 6237 THEN 'Legels Fees'
    WHEN 6262 THEN 'Staff Hiring Costs'
    ELSE 'General Expenses'
    END AS [AccountDesc],
 rtrim(GLCode.ACTNUMST) as [AccountNum],
 GLCode.ACTNUMBR_2 as [ServiceLine],
 GLCode.ACTNUMBR_4 as [Partner],
 sum(Budget.BUDGETAMT) over (partition by rtrim(GLCode.ACTNUMST)) as [Budget]

FROM
 GL20000 as GLTrans
 LEFT JOIN GL00105 as GLCode on GLCode.ACTINDX = GLTrans.ACTINDX
 LEFT JOIN GL00201 as Budget on (rtrim(Budget.ACTNUMBR_1) + '-' + rtrim(Budget.ACTNUMBR_2) + '-' + rtrim(Budget.ACTNUMBR_3) + '-' + rtrim(Budget.ACTNUMBR_4)) = rtrim(GLCode.ACTNUMST)
                            and Budget.BUDGETID = '2016 BUDGET'
                            and Budget.ACTNUMBR_1 in ('6238', '6212', '6216', '6217', '6250', '6265', '6270', '6272', '6268', '6237', '6262', '6213', '6214', '6215')
                            and Budget.ACTNUMBR_2  in ('RAS', 'BRI', 'COR')

WHERE
 GLCode.ACTNUMBR_1 in ('6238', '6212', '6216', '6217', '6250', '6265', '6270', '6272', '6268', '6237', '6262', '6213', '6214', '6215')
 and GLCode.ACTNUMBR_2  in ('RAS', 'BRI', 'COR')
 and GLTrans.TRXDATE >= '2015-07-01 00:00:00.000'
 and GLTrans.TRXDATE <= dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, getdate()), 0)

GROUP BY
 GLTrans.OPENYEAR, GLTrans.REFRENCE, GLTrans.DSCRIPTN, GLTrans.TRXDATE, GLTrans.DEBITAMT,
 GLCode.ACTNUMST, GLCode.ACTNUMBR_1, GLCode.ACTNUMBR_2, GLCode.ACTNUMBR_4, GLTrans.TRXDATE,
 GLTrans.DEBITAMT, GLTrans.CRDTAMNT, GLTrans.DEX_ROW_ID
```

I took some liberties with the formatting, I find it easier to read this way. The changes I've made include:

1. Your first case statement can be replaced with a single line that creates the same output.
2. Your second case statement can be written slightly differently to take up less space.
3. Your final join can be written outside of a subquery. I'm not sure if this will satisfy the join criteria you need (you had `SELECT TOP 1000` in there, which I'm not sure is needed). I'm not sure what the relationship is between your budget table and the transactions table.
4. Added a `sum(column) over (partition by another_column)`, which is similar to how Excel offers subtotals in pivot tables.

Can you provide some sample data so we can better understand the relationships between your tables? If you put them in `{code blocks}` they are easy to format with the fixed character widths, like this:

```
Table 1:

| Column_1  | Column_2        | Column_3  |
|-----------|-----------------|-----------|
| some data | some other data | more data |
| etc       | second row      | stuff     |
```

**UPDATE:**

So, looking at your desired results, it might actually be easier to solve this in Excel rather than in your SQL query. It can be done in SQL, but it will be a lot more complex, requiring CTEs with `ROW_NUMBER`, `CASE` and `ORDER BY` just to specify which rows you want to include the budget figure on, and which you want to return a `null` value on.

If you stick with your existing output (assuming you are currently putting that in columns A thru D), then you can put this formula in E2 and drag it down to autofill the rows below:

```
=IF(MID(A2,IFERROR(FIND(" ",A2)+1,1),3)<>MID(A1,IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1)+1,1),3),D2,"")
```

This might look complicated but it's really a very simple true/false comparison. The `FIND` function looks for the character position of the first space in A1/A2, (`IFERROR` is there to return a default value of 1 in case no spaces are found), next the `MID` function starts at that character position and returns the next 3 characters to the right ('Jul', 'Aug', etc). The whole thing is performed twice - once for the current row, and once for the previous row. If the values are different, it indicates that the month has changed, and therefore returns the corresponding values in the budget column (D), if the values are the same, then the month hasn't progressed yet and so it returns blank. You can have your pivot table sum by this column and it should work fine because there is only one row for each month that has a budget value copied from column D.

Comment: I've amended the original question.  Apologies for the confusion.  This is my first time on here.  It wasn't overly clear how to display sample data!  (Thanks JoeMalpass for your advise above)

Comment: JoeMalpass - I showed your comments to my colleague and he said thanks for suggestion four.  That is a very useful idea.  TBH I don't really understand it but I'll do some research and see what I can find out.

Also thanks for the edits to the codes re. point 1 & 2 these are very useful to know.

Comment: @DebbsR I've updated my answer. I'm actually going to recommend solving this in Excel rather than SQL, it's quite a bit less complicated.